# typedoc/jsdoc document generic parameter (callback arguments)

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdoc, jsdoc3, typedoc

I have the following code:

```
type AlarmEvent = events.Event<(name: Alarm) => void>;
```

As you can see, the event class takes a generic parameter in the form of a function signature, which I'd like to document.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using [TypeDoc](http://typedoc.org/) or JSDoc?

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is a place to hang normal JSDocs off of, you can just create another type:

```
type AlarmHandler = (name: Alarm) => void
type AlarmEvent = events.Event<AlarmHandler>
```

If you need this to work with JSDoc you can use [the `@callback` tag](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-callback.html) in a standalone JSDoc comment to do the work:

```
/**
 * Handles alarm events
 * @callback
 * @param {Alarm} name The alarm that fired
*/
```